Model Does not Follow the Armature
this is my first time trying to animate therefore i don't have the information to stick the model at one point. Every information has been given down below:

BEFORE:

AFTER:

Additional Info:
Leg bones are not connected to body.
IK bones does not have any parents.
TLDR; How can i make it move as armature bone moves?


hello could you please share your file?

Hello, I never done that before, can you tell me how?

read the instructions here https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload

sorry I cannot download it even though it is 1mb,  do you have any communication app like discord or skype?

use workupload?

Download? You should upload it there by following the instructions given there, not download it... what exactly is not working?

Excuse me for confusing one to another... i cannot UPLOAD the file. When i drag it to the file drop segment it takes forever it to UPLOAD and UPLOAD bar doesn't move at all.

@moonboots https://workupload.com/file/JpC3mwmmTLx

I've added your file into your question so that it can be downloaded easily. (You have to add the URL of your question into the field on the upload page as per the instructions and click 'Upload' before the upload bar will move.)

You just parented the leg to the leg controller, it is not the correct way to do it, so first thing remove this parentage:

Instead join all the objects together with CtrlJ, then select the object, shift select the armature and CtrlP > Set Parent To > (Armature Deform) With Empty Groups. This will create as many vertex group in your object as you have bones. Now select a limb in Edit mode and assign it to the correct vertex group (there's a problem with your topology though, as it is not aligned with the bones, so you maybe fix that before assigning):

Another solution would be to parent With Automatic Weights and let Blender assign the vertices itself, if it gives good results.
Also maybe the bone called Back_body should be reversed so that it points backwards.

I am sorry, I will try my best to replicate what you write but if it isn't too much to ask, can you send back the file with the changes?

OKAY I fixed it, thank you so much man!
